# Unable to create a user using a custom form using devise in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

Im having a problem creating a devise user using a custom form. Whenever I submit the form I get an error saying the email and password fields cant be blank, It seems that the problem is something to do with the parameters not being permitted. I Have tried creating my own sign_up_params method to permit them manually but it still doesn't work and keep seeing the error.

Here is my code:

This is the form I am submitting:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4>Sign Up</h4>
   </div>
   <div class="panel-body">
      <%= form_for resource, url: user_registration_path do |f| %>
        <%= devise_error_messages! %>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <%= f.label :email, "Email: ", class: "col-sm-2" %>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control' %>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <%= f.label :password, "Password: ", class: "col-sm-2 col-form-label" %>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control' %>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group row">
            <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation: ", class: "col-sm-2 col-form-label" %>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control' %>
            </div>
        </div>

        <%= f.submit "Sign Up", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    <% end %>
</div>
</div>
```

And this is the controller:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    include DeviseHelper

    def new
    end

    protected

    def sign_up_params
        params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

Also my routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    root 'users/registrations#new'
  devise_for :users, controllers: {registrations: 'users/registrations', sessions: 'users/sessions'}
end
```

This is really starting to bug me now as Ive set up devise plenty of times before and never had this issue. If anyone could help me out here it would be really appreciated

Comment: could you post the error please.

Comment: Also do you have a create method? if so, could you use a byebug and post your params please.

Comment: Like Gabriel mentioned, please narrow post the specific error you get, is User validation failing?, are params not making back to controller?, are params not in the format they way they are permitted in `signup_params`